# Dynamically Render Columns In DataTable - Column.Render Property

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I am working on developing a dynamic DataTable in which the data source is dynamically generated with [n] columns, where the data source may contain 4 columns or 6 columns as an example. As per this post on the DataTables forum ([How to Render Columns from a dynamic data source](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/50309/how-to-render-the-columns-or-columndefs-for-a-dynamic-data-source)) it is possible to define and build a variable of a column defintions, and pass this to the initialisation.

Based on this I have created the following code that works well for the given purpose and renders the columns dynaically based on the data source.

HTML:

```
 <div class="data-table">
        <table id="dataTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%;"></table>
    </div>
```

Script:

```
 <script>
    var dataToSend = {};
    var dataTable;

    dataToSend = {
        "regionId": @Model.RegionId
    }

    // Get Column Defintions
    var dtColumns = @Html.Raw(Json.`enter code here`Serialize(listOfDefintions));

    // DataTable
    $(function () {
        dataTable = {
            dt: null,

            init: function () {
                dt = $("#dataTable").DataTable({
                    ajax: {
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "@Url.Action("GetDataForGrid", "Contact")",
                        data: function () {
                            return dataToSend;
                        },
                        datatype: "json",
                        dataSrc: ""
                    },
                    columns: dtColumns,
                    lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, 100], [10, 25, 50, 100]],
                });
            },
            refresh: function () {
                dt.ajax.reload();
            }
        }

        dataTable.init();
    });

</script>
```

The above code renders the following DataTable, based on the data source which can be seen below.

DataSource:
[image: Data Source]

Rendered Table:
[image: DataTable]

My question regards the empty final column of the table, in which I need to render a button. I would have normally written something along the lines of the code below, if I had been wanting to render a table with known column values, in which I would use the DataTable property column.Render. As you can see below, using the data property of the column, I can use create a function to render a button, which can be used to quick navigate to the Contact/Edit page passing the "id" as a Url route value, meaning that it is possible to edit the specific details of the choosen contact.

```
 <script>
    var dataToSend = {};
    var contactDataTable;

    dataToSend = {
       "regionId": @Model.RegionId
    };

    $(function () {
        contactDataTable = {
            dt: null,

            init: function () {
                dt = $('#contact-data-table').DataTable({
                    ajax: {
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "@Url.Action("GetDataForGrid", "Contact")",
                        data: function () {
                            return dataToSend;
                        },
                        datatype: "json",
                        dataSrc: ""
                    },
                    columns: [
                        {
                            "title": "Forename",
                            "data": "forename",
                            "searchable": true,
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Surname",
                            "data": "surname",
                            "searchable": true,
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Email",
                            "data": "email",
                            "searchable": true
                        },
                        {
                            "Status":
                            "status":
                            "searchable":
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Role",
                            "data": "roleName",
                            "searchable": true
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "",
                            "data": "id",
                            "searchable": false,
                            "sortable": false,
                            "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                                var buffer = '<a href="@Url.Action("Edit","Contact")/' + data  + '" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary js-action"><i class="far fa-edit"></i></a>&nbsp;'

                                buffer += '<a href="@Url.Action("Delete", "Contact")/' + data + '" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger js-action"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></a>';

                                return buffer;
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    columnDefs: [
                        { "width": "15%", "targets": 0 },
                        { "width": "15%", "targets": 1 },
                        { "width": "20%", "targets": 2 },
                        { "width": "15%", "targets": 3 },
                        { "width": "15%", "targets": 4 },
                        { "width": "20%", "targets": 5 },
                    ],
                    lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, 100], [10, 25, 50, 100]],
                });
            },
            refresh: function () {
                dt.ajax.reload();
            }
        }
</script>
```

How can I achieve the same principle of rendering a button in my table if I am defining and building my column defintion variable before passing this to my DataTable intialization?

Any help would be great.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand... You seem to be heading in a good direction, it should be possible to use the data-variable to construct a URL that passes the id - so where's the problem?

Comment: Suggestion: Instead of using `dataSrc: ""`, use a function: `dataSrc: function ( json ) { ... }`. You can see an example [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc). This allows you to iterate over your source JSON data, and add a new object to each row - where the object is a string containing the HTML for the button you want to build. This is the equivalent to the logic you wanted to use in your column renderer.

Comment: @MBaas - In the example provided I was looking to render a button in the final column of the table, in which I was having difficulties acutally rendering the HTML element. In my various iterations to solve this problem, I was either able to render a button but not access the data property of the column, which in this case is the Id, and visa versa.

Comment: I have been able to resolve the problem in the meanwhile, which i will happily post if desired. I can problally look to resolve the issue as andrewJames suggests, however I found that simply setting the Data property of the final column to null, and defaultContent to render a simple button worked well. I then developed a on click event which obtained the data for the current row, in which I could access the Id property to use within the construction of my URL. There is mostly likely a better approach, in which case I will look to implement.

Comment: That's a good, straightforward solution. You are welcome to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) - you can also accept it, if you want. That will help future visitors to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution to the given problem is to use the `Column.defaultContent` property and a custom `onClick` event that can be used to construct the relevant URL required.

In the example below, I've modified my `dtColumns` array as seen in the provided image, so that the relevant object contain a definition for `defaultContent`, set to a string that will render a simple button. For the `defaultContent` to be used by the `DataTable`, you must set the `Data` property to null.

DataTable - Data Source

```
var myColumnDefs = [
        { title: "Forename", data: "forename", width: "15%"},
        { title: "Surname", data: "surname", width: "15%"},
        { title: "Email", data: "email", width: "20%"},
        { title: "Status", data: "status", width: "15%"},
        { title: "Role", data: "roleName", width: "15%"},
        { title: "", data: "(string)null", width: "20%", searchable: false, sortable: false, defaultContent: "<a id='btnEdit' class='btn btn-sm btn-primary js-action'><i class='fas fa-edit'></i></a>"}
    ]
```

In doing so, a table such as the one below is rendered:

[image: Rendered DataTable]

The modified code really only includes extra functions to handle the `onClick` event of the buttons. In this case, I can obtain the data of the loaded record by using `$("#dataTable").DataTable().row((selectedRow).parents("tr")).data()`, in which the id property can be accessed. Using this Id value I was then able to construct the desired URL which happens to be passed into a function that renders a Bootstrap Modal.

```
    <script>
    var dataToSend = {};
    var dataTable;

    // Set Data To Send
    dataToSend = {
        "regionId": "@Model.RegionId"
    }

    // Get Column Defintions
    var dtColumns = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(listOfDefintions));

    // DataTable
    $(function () {
        dataTable = {
            dt: null,

            init: function () {
                dt = $("#dataTable").DataTable({
                    ajax: {
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "@Url.Action("GetDataForGrid", "Contact")",
                        data: function () {
                            return dataToSend;
                        },
                        datatype: "json",
                        dataSrc: ""
                    },
                    columns: dtColumns,
                    lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, 100], [10, 25, 50, 100]],
                });
            },
            refresh: function () {
                dt.ajax.reload();
            }
        }

        dynaGridDataTable.init();


        // DataTable Buttons
        $("#dataTable").on("click", ".js-action", function (event) {
            var btnId = $(this).attr("id");
            var recordId = getRecordId($(this));

            if (btnId !== undefined && btnId == "btnEdit") {
                // Create Edit URL
                var href = '@Url.Action("Popup", "DynaGrid")?appGridName=@Model.AppGrid.GridName&masterRecordId=@Model.AppGrid.MasterRecordFKId&id=' + recordId + '';
                
                renderModalForDataTableButton(href);
            } else if (btnId !== undefined && btnId == "btnDelete") {
                // Code 
                
            } else {
                alert("Something Went Wrong - Unable To Redirect");
            }
        });

        // Get Record Id Of Current Row
        function getRecordId(selectedRow) {
            var data = $("#dataTable").DataTable().row((selectedRow).parents("tr")).data();
            return data.id;
        }

        function renderModalForDataTableButton(href) {
            $.get(href, function (data) {
                $('#myModalContent').html(data);
                $('#myModal').modal('show');
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please prefer to type up code, logs, etc instead of screenshotting. This makes it more readable for many users AND indexable by search engine bots.